# Is there a simple list widget in android that lets me select from a list without having to create an adapter?

Tags: android, list, widget

I have a list, I want the user to select one. It's a string. Maybe even have an Object I can associate with it.
Is there any way to do this without creating a subclass with an arrayadapter?
I see tons of examples and they all seem overengineered for what must be the most basic list handling problem in the world. Is there no default simple list string handler built in? 
If there is, I can't find it.
Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no default simple list string handler built in?

`ListView` is a simple list string handler that's built in.

> Is there any way to do this without creating a subclass with an
>   arrayadapter?

You don't have to subclass `ArrayAdapter` to use it. Binding the data to `ListView` is one line of code:

```
final ListView list = ...;
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
```

In your case, `data` would either be a `List<String>` or a `String[]`.

Comment: My confusion was in not realizing that R.layout.simple_list_item_1 was an android constant and not something that nobody was including in their samples.

Comment: I'm missing one more little nugget of information. The list when displayed in my layout takes up most of the viewing area. I've seen other apps have the currently selected item show and then when clicked, the entire list pops up on top to make the list viewable and selectable. Is there a switch for that or do I have to implement the entire effect myself?

Comment: @stu Sounds like you want `AlertDialog.Builder.setItems`.